# Get object from client validation attribute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have next "AddValidation" method in client validation attribute (inherited from ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator)

```
public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
    {
        var viewContext = context.ActionContext as ViewContext;
        var modelType = context.ModelMetadata.ContainerType;
        var model = viewContext?.ViewData.Model;
        var maxDate = (DateTime?)modelType.GetProperty(_maxDateName)?.GetValue(model, null);
        var minDate = (DateTime?)modelType.GetProperty(_minDateName)?.GetValue(model, null);
         var errorMessage = string.Format(ErrorMessageString, minDate?.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), maxDate?.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
        
        context.Attributes.Add("data-val-preliminaryraterangedate", errorMessage);
        context.Attributes.Add("data-val-preliminaryraterangedate-rangedates",
            JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {MaxDateName = $"#{_maxDateName}", MinDateName = $"#{_minDateName}"}));
    }
```

How can I get model object to get the properties values? This example is good only if model object contains primitive types. And cannot work with model object that contains complex type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var viewContext = context.ActionContext as ViewContext;
        var modelType = context.ModelMetadata.ContainerType;
        var instance = viewContext?.ViewData.Model;
        var model = instance?.GetType().Name == modelType.Name
            ? instance
            : instance?.GetType()?.GetProperties().First(x => x.PropertyType.Name == modelType.Name)
                .GetValue(instance, null);
        var maxDate = (DateTime?)modelType.GetProperty(_maxDateName)?.GetValue(model, null);
        var minDate = (DateTime?)modelType.GetProperty(_minDateName)?.GetValue(model, null);
         var errorMessage = string.Format(ErrorMessageString, minDate?.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), maxDate?.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
        
        context.Attributes.Add("data-val-preliminaryraterangedate", errorMessage);
        context.Attributes.Add("data-val-preliminaryraterangedate-rangedates",
            JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {MaxDateName = $"#{_maxDateName}", MinDateName = $"#{_minDateName}"}));
```

You can get type that you need from `context.ModelMetadata.ContainerType;` and compare it with parent model property type

Comment: You are a lifesaver! This is super useful. A minor nitpick, it should probably be var model = instance?.GetType().FullName == modelType.FullName (I have a viewmodel with the same type name as one of its properties, but different namespace... I swear I will clean my mess up). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can directly get the property by `model`, but you need specify its type.

Below is a demo:

**Model:**

```
public class TimeModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MyTime MyTime { get; set; }
}
public class MyTime
{
    [Ranges]
    public DateTime RangeDatetime { get; set; }
}
```

**RangesAttribute:**

```
public class RangesAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator
{
    public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
    {
        var viewContext = context.ActionContext as ViewContext;
        var modelType = context.ModelMetadata.ContainerType;
        var model = (TimeModel)viewContext?.ViewData.Model;
        var name = model.Name;
        var rangeDatetime = model.MyTime.RangeDatetime
        //...
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    TimeModel model = new TimeModel
    {
        Name = "AAAAA",
        MyTime = new MyTime {  RangeDatetime = DateTime.Now}
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Update:**

```
public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
{
    var viewContext = context.ActionContext as ViewContext;
    var model = viewContext.ViewData.Model;
    Dictionary<string, string> myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    Type type = model.GetType();
    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in type.GetProperties())
    {
        var subModel = pi.GetValue(model, null);
        Type subtype = pi.GetValue(model, null).GetType();
        if (!subtype.IsPrimitive && !subtype.Equals(typeof(string)))
        {
            var pii = subtype.GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo item in pii)
            {
                myDict[item.Name] = item.GetValue(subModel, null)?.ToString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            myDict[pi.Name] = pi.GetValue(model, null)?.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice point, but what if I have different models `var model = (TimeModel)viewContext?.ViewData.Model;` not only TimeModel

Comment: and also it breaks case when model object contains only primitive types

Comment: If the model is dynamic, you may need use reflection, see my update.

Comment: Good solution but it works only if there is only one complex model in model, please see my solution below how I resolved this case.